# Installing Eav Attributes with db_schema.xml

Tags: magento-2.3

I am wondering how and where eav-attributes should be installed in Magento 2.3. I know that they were installed in the previous versions of Magento via InstallData.php or UpgradeData.php.

To me it does not look like there would be a way to configure them in a etc/db_schema.xml.

Would this be properly done in a Vendor/Modulename/Setup/Patch/Data/Patch.php file via the apply() method?

Comment: Hi  Shanteshwar Inde, I am more interested in the best practise approach

Comment: I found an answer to this question. It is documented here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/migration-commands.html. 

All previous files which lived in the Setup directory can be converted via command line into declarative schema.